# How to use Google, Facebook & Spotify in same App Delegate in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, google-plus, spotify, appdelegate

I am making an app where I am using Google, Facebook & Spotify. So, I am using below code in my App Delegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool
    {
        //For Google & Facebook
        let sourceApplication =  options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
        let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]

        let googleHandler = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
            url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation )

        let facebookHandler = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application (
            application,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation )

        return googleHandler || facebookHandler


        //For Spotify
        if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url) {
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url) { error, session in
                // This is the callback that'll be triggered when auth is completed (or fails).
                if error != nil {
                    print("*** Auth error: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                else {
                    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session
                }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "sessionUpdated"), object: self)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Problem: How can I combine with only one return value in App Delegate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
             open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool
{
     //For Google & Facebook
  let sourceApplication =   options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]


var Spotify = false

//For Spotify
if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url)
{
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url)
    { error, session in
        // This is the callback that'll be triggered when auth is completed (or fails).
        if error != nil
        {
            print("*** Auth error: \(error)")


        }
        else
        {
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session

             Spotify = true

        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "sessionUpdated"), object: self)


    }
}



let googleHandler = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
                                                      url,
                                                      sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                      annotation: annotation )

let facebookHandler = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application (
                                                                             application,
                                                                             open: url,
                                                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                             annotation: annotation )

return googleHandler || facebookHandler || Spotify



}
```